# debian host resolving error

Tags: networking, dns, debian

I have some problem with resolving hostnames with ping and in my browser.

If I ping any non-existent domain name (as jhdevjfejbhbdufb.com), I get local IP adress as a response (external ip). But nslookup can't find this host name. 
A browser opens a local web server when entering this host name.
Why this can happen?

Comment: can you post the output

Comment: counterkill@xedus:~$ ping jhdevjfejbhbdufb.com
`PING xedus.sytes.net (37.220.180.119) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 37.220.180.119: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.064 ms
64 bytes from 37.220.180.119: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
64 bytes from 37.220.180.119: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
--- xedus.sytes.net ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.037/0.048/0.064/0.012 ms`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/513237/nslookup-fails-but-ping-succeeds-for-nonexistent-domains#515661 
this is for FreeBSD but it should work with Debian. 
/etc/resolv.conf (and variations thereof) is used to resolve domain names in pretty much every unix-like operating system.

It's possible that someone is rerouting your traffic to their site. Namely xedus.sytes.net. It's called DNS hijacking and domain name registrars and isps often do it. 
You could block the ip address it directs you to with
iptables. That way you wont get any packets from them and the ping should fail.

```
 iptables -A INPUT -s 37.220.180.119 -j DROP
```

Don't do that if you ever actually use the server that's redirecting you. (you said "local server" so I'm not sure) It's a primitive solution, instead people use things like dd-wrt to prevent DNS hijacking. http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf    then do exactly what the first answer said :D

Comment: What? I don't understand why you commented that? Please edit your answer to include the actual solution to the problem instead of just a link.

Comment: I commented it because I didn't know enter would submit. I was trying to add spacing. :/

Comment: Sorry, I see the full comment now, anyway, link answers are not accepted here, you should include the steps to fix the actual issue and provide the link for reference. A answer that is just a link will get deleted. If you edit it, I will vote you up.

Comment: This server is located on local machine, but opened from internet. Thanks.